# Track Sagging Floor Over Time

Tags: floor, tools, level

We recently moved some furniture around in our 100+ year old house, and it's drawn attention to the fact that some of our floors aren't 100% level.  I can't really tell if this is something that's new, or if it's always been a problem but I've never noticed.

Are there tools available for me to track the sagging over a period of time to see if it's getting worse?  I have a level but there's no great way (for me) to track whether the bubble's moved more or less during over a period of time.  My mobile phone as a level app, but I assume that's more for fun that an accurate tool.

Also, if the problem is getting what sort of professional would I want to bring in the assess the problem, and what sort of professional *might* I need to fix the problem?

Comment: you cannot track sagging just by doing one measurement

Answer (score 1):

Cheap hand laser pointer will do the job. Mount it to a flat piece of wood, or whatever. Duct tape will work fine Put the thing on the floor and lightly mark where you put it. Turn the laser on and mark where the beam intersects the wall.
wait six months and repeat. Is the mark on the wall in a different place? Then you've likely got sagging. It's easiest to figure out what's going on if you mark the wall at several different locations with the laser in one spot; the repeat the same a few times with the mounted laser in different spots.
You needn't worry about your laser mount being level, as long as its the saame each time.

You can buy a laser level at a big box store, but it's a lot more expensive and does exactly the same job as a $1 cat laser yopu can buy at most dollar stores.